# how to send an image from cfclient.camera.getPictureFromAlbum

Tags: file, coldfusion, cfclient

I am trying to upload an image to server which is coming from an image library. First part works by using :

```
 <cffunction access="public" name="getPicAlbum" returntype="void" >
     <cfset opt = cfclient.camera.getOptions()>
     <cfset res = cfclient.camera.getPictureFromAlbum(opt,true)>
     <cfset displayMessage("picAlbum <br><hr>", false)>
     <cfset document.getElementById('imgBase64').value=#res#>
     <cfset uploadImgAsJpg()>
 </cffunction>
```

Once I read the image, I put the base64 value into a hidden text field. Then, I call uploadImgAsJpg() function.

```
 function uploadImgAsJpg()  {
    var base64Img = document.getElementById('imgBase64').value; 
    try {
        myImage = cfclient.file.readAsBase64(base64Img);
        cfclient.file.write("newImg.jpg", myImage);
        // where does this newImg.jpg go?
        var oldFileSystem = cfclient.file.getFileSystem();
        //Get file object from the path
        var fileObj = cfclient.file.get("newImg.jpg");

        displayMessage("uploadImgAsJpg image - " + fileObj.fullPath + "<br><hr>", false);

        var newFilePath = copyFileFromTempToPersistentFileSystem(fileObj.fullPath);

                        //Now upload file to the server
                        uploadFileToServer(newFilePath);

                        //Delete temporary file
                        cfclient.file.remove(fileObj.fullPath);
                        displayMessage("Deleted temporaty file " + fileObj.fullPath + "<br><hr>");
                    } catch (any e) {
                        displayMessage("ERROR " + e.message + "<br><hr>");
                        displayMessage("ERROR " + e.detail + "<br><hr>");
                        displayMessage("ERROR " + e.TagContext + "<br><hr>");
                    }

                }
```

Some of this code was copied from http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/cfmobile-example-taking-picture-and-uploading-to-coldfusion-server/

When I run the code above, my cfcatch displays : ERROR File/Directory specified was not found.

Where does cfclient.file.write save a file? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my problem. this gets a picture from library and sends it to the server.

hope it helps someone else.

```
<cffunction access="public" name="getPicAlbum" returntype="void" >
    <cfset opt = cfclient.camera.getOptions()>
    <cfset res = cfclient.camera.getPictureFromAlbum(opt,false)>
    <cfset imgStr  = cfclient.file.readAsBase64(res)>
    <cfset imgFile = cfclient.file.write("newImg.jpg",imgStr)>
    <cfset cfclient.file.upload("newImg.jpg","xxx.com/?vw=uploadBase64",uploadSuccess,onUploadError)>
 </cffunction>
```